# Outlook unable to handle bracket > in e-mail correctly

Tags: outlook

I have an external system feeding draft e-mail in outlook.
The e-mail address is in format:
Username <abcd@gmail.com; efgh@gmail.com>

When I preview e-mail in outbox, the outlook wrongly treated the e-mail as "Username <abcd@gmail.com" and "efgh@gmail.com>"
But, if I type the above wordings manually, Outlook 2016 check name feature can correctly recognize:
Username abcd@gmail.com; efgh@gmail.com
Any thoughts why Outlook cannot check names properly for system generated e-mail? The external system correctly transfer the string to Outlook "Username <abcd@gmail.com; efgh@gmail.com>"

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Recipient.Resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Recipient.Resolve) method which attempts to resolve a `Recipient` object against the Address Book.

```
Sub AssignTask()
 Dim myItem As Outlook.TaskItem 
 Dim myDelegate As Outlook.Recipient  
 Set MyItem = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)  

 MyItem.Assign 
 
 Set myDelegate = MyItem.Recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev") 
 
 myDelegate.Resolve 
 
 If myDelegate.Resolved Then  
   myItem.Subject = "Prepare Agenda For Meeting" 
   myItem.DueDate = Now + 30  
   myItem.Display  
   myItem.Send  
 End If 
 
End Sub
```

You may also find the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article helpful.

Comment: This sounds interesting! What if the recipients cannot be stored in address book, because the list of the recipients always change?
The list Username <abcd@gmail.com; efgh@gmail.com> is from an external system and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

`Username <abcd@gmail.com; efgh@gmail.com>` format is incorrect. It must be `Username <abcd@gmail.com>; Username <efgh@gmail.com>`

Comment: I think you are right. Your format is ideal. But my format still works if you type in manually. And outlook would assume the 2nd e-mail has no name.

Comment: It is not my format - it is RFC. Whatever application creates data in the wrong format has a bug.